# Can Github Copilot look at the context of a project with multiple files?

Tags: github, github-copilot

Or it only analyzes and autocompletes using the context of standalone files regardless of additional files in my project?

Comment: The last Copilot update from Nov. 2023 introduces the notion of `@workspace`. See [my edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77023887/6309).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Possibly: ([GitHub Copilot – November 30th 2023 Update](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-11-30-github-copilot-november-30th-update/))

> ### Introducing “agents” in Copilot Chat in VSCode
>
> We have introduced a new capability called “**agents**” to enhance your interaction with Copilot Chat.
>
> Agents are like specialized experts who can assist you with specific tasks. You can mention them in the chat using the `@` symbol.
>
> Currently, there are two agents available:
>
> - **`@workspace`**: This agent has knowledge about the code in your workspace and can help you navigate it by finding relevant files or classes. The @workspace agent uses a meta prompt to determine what information to collect from the workspace to help answer your question.
> - `@vscode`: This agent is knowledgeable about commands and features in the VSCode editor itself, and can assist you in using them.

See [VScode 1.84](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_84#_chat-agents)

> ### @workspace
>
> The `@workspace` agent uses a meta prompt to determine what information to collect from the workspace to help answer your question.
>
> One approach used by the meta prompt is to look back at your conversation history to resolve ambiguous words/phrases in a question.
> For example, if you ask `@workspace What does it do?`, the meta prompt will now consider the history to figure out what `it` actually is and what information to collect to answer the question.
> The meta prompt also uses a wide set of terms, including more synonyms, to generate a list of potentially relevant terms.
>
> File paths and symbols in `@workspace` responses are clickable links. This makes it easy to navigate to the code that Copilot is referring to.
>
> The @workspace agent respects the `.gitignore` and `.copilotignore` when deciding which files from the workspace to index.
> Agents replace slash comm

---

Not yet (Aug. 2023).

The latest [GitHub Copilot – August 28th Update](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-08-28-github-copilot-august-28th-update/):

- mentioned an "[extended context](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-08-28-github-copilot-august-28th-update/#updated-quick-chat-experience)" beyond code files, taking in the active terminal’s buffer and selection to better inform its responses. See [VsCode 1.81](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_81#_inline-chat)
- referenced the Aug. 22nd, 2023 blog post "[Simplified Code Refinement and Debugging with GitHub Copilot Chat](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/simplified-code-refinement-and-debugging-with-github-copilot-chat/)" from [Mark Wilson-Thomas](https://github.com/markw-t), the program Manager on Microsoft Visual Studio and GitHub Copilot Chat for VSCode, and [Mark Downie](https://github.com/poppastring).

In the comments of that blog post, Andreas Saurwein adds:

> for enterprise use it needs more context, like on the solution level, it must be able to understand the WHOLE solution code not only the opened files, or whatever is its current context level.
> Most often Copilot does not understand how some of the classes used actually work, and it does not suggest them in new code even if previous code did use them.

And Mark (Wilson-Thomas) answers:

> We are definitely aware of this requirement for whole solution context. If you can share some cases that would be particularly important to your usage in this regard that would be great and help the team prioritize the most useful cases.
>
> It sounds like you’re looking for understanding/explanation/diagnosis that spans multiple files in the solution as your main case?

That last sentence illustrates that GitHub Copilot does not work at a project level yet.

Answer (score 4):

Currently is it on the WIP stage.

https://githubnext.com/projects/copilot-view/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34131290)

Comment: This page seems to say the contrary: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/13617

Answer (score 4):

This is a very dynamic area of research/product development. As of Sep 2023 open tabs (see below for references) are used for context, (not: the whole project, solution, or the repo). Work is [being done](https://githubnext.com/projects/copilot-view/) on expanding this.

Please note that how the actual prompt for the underlying model is created is not as simple as pasting all the source code from all the files.

GitHub's [How GitHub Copilot is getting better at understanding your code](https://github.blog/2023-05-17-how-github-copilot-is-getting-better-at-understanding-your-code/#how-github-copilot-understands-your-code) from May 2023 provides a window to the process.

Here's simplistic summary based on the article:

1. > It all comes down to prompts, which are compilations of IDE code and relevant context that’s fed to the model. Prompts are generated by algorithms in the background, at any point in your coding.
2. > Here’s how a prompt is created: a series of algorithms first select relevant code snippets or comments from your current file and other sources (which we’ll dive into below). These snippets and comments are then prioritized, filtered, and assembled into the final prompt.
   >
   > (...)
   >
   > Most of this work takes place in what’s called a prompt library, which is where our in-house ML experts work with algorithms to extract and prioritize a variety of sources of information about the developer’s context,
3. > The Fill-In-the-Middle (FIM) paradigm widened the context aperture even more. Prior to FIM, only the code before your cursor would be put into the prompt—ignoring the code after your cursor.
4. > we’re experimenting with vector databases that could create a customized coding experience for developers working in private repositories or with proprietary code. (...)
   >
   > What’s a vector database? (...)

---

References for "uses open tabs":

1. In the the official [AI Tools in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/artificial-intelligence) in *Provide Context* section it says:

   > Open files
   >
   > Copilot looks at the current and open files in your editor to analyze the context and create appropriate suggestions. Having related files open in VS Code while using Copilot helps set this context and lets the Copilot see a bigger picture of your project.
2. In GitHub's [How GitHub Copilot is getting better at understanding your code](https://github.blog/2023-05-17-how-github-copilot-is-getting-better-at-understanding-your-code/#how-github-copilot-understands-your-code) from May 2023 it says:

   > **Neighboring tabs** is what we call the technique that allows GitHub Copilot to process all of the files open in a developer’s IDE instead of just the single one the developer is working on. By opening all files relevant to their project, developers automatically invoke GitHub Copilot to comb through all of the data and find matching pieces of code between their open files and the code around their cursor—and add those matches to the prompt.
   >
   > (...)
   >
   > [image: nputs for the model: open tabs, data from editor, vector database]

Answer (score 3):

You can type this in Github Copilot Chat:

```
@workspace Write the README.md file using the current workspace in markdown format
```

Answer (score -2):

as their announcements and details, It currently look at the context of the files you are editing, however not yet have ability to look at the context of your entire codebase, and also they hope to add this functionality future.

as my suggestion, But it can be dependents and we can't trust any thing 100%.