# How to use GitHub Copilot for multiple files?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I am looking to explore GitHub Copilot. I don't have in-depth coding experience and I graduated just a few months ago. I was planning to build a small website to explore what GitHub copilot has to offer.

When I added comments for the copilot to generate code, it wasn't generating the required code. In the html file, I commented that I want to create text with glitch animations and a section containing the header, navigation icon and to play a video on loop. It wasn't able to generate code that I wanted. So, how do I use it for code that requires reference for other files too(.css or .js files). I'm still learning about front end since I've most experience in C, C++ and Core Java.

Comment: one _can_ write CSS and JS in HTML (see the `<style>` and `<script>` tags).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to do anything, GitHub copilot automatically takes context from the css and js files when using html file.

Answer (score 2):

Since Q1 2024, you can specify a list of files you need Copilot to work on:

> ### [Code faster and better with GitHub Copilot’s new features in Visual Studio](https://github.blog/changelog/2024-01-30-code-faster-and-better-with-github-copilots-new-features-in-visual-studio) (Jan. 2024)
>
> We have introduced two new powerful features to the latest Visual Studio Copilot Chat extension: slash commands (`/`) that allow you to direct Copilot to perform specific tasks, and context Variables (`#`) that allow you to specify a file for Copilot to focus its answer on.
> These features are available on the latest [Chat extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioExptTeam.VSGitHubCopilot) that is compatible with [Visual Studio 2022 version 17.8 and higher](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/).
>
> The context variables feature enables you to add files from your solution into your questions using the `#` symbol.
> By referencing a file in this way, you allow Copilot to access the content of the file and provide more targeted answers about it.
> For example, you can ask “How does the `#file:'Main.cs'` file work?” or “What is the purpose of the `#file:'Calculator.cs'` file?” and get relevant answers from Copilot Chat.
> You can add multiple files to one question.
>
> [image: https://github.blog/wp-content/uploads/2024/01/image1_bcdd08.jpg?w=934&resize=934%2C1024]
>
> Besides these main features, you can also explore our other exciting new [preview features](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/copilot-chat-slash-commands-and-context-variables/)
>
> Join the discussion within [GitHub Community](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/categories/copilot).

That means you can ask:

"Considering the `#file:'Main.cs'` and `#file:'Calculator.cs'`, how would you implement function X()"

Comment: Is there a way how to force it to actually incorporate the file contents somehow? Or maybe there's some hard limit on how much it can consume?

Comment: @jave.web GitHub Copilot attempts to incorporate the contents of these files into its suggestions. It reads the context from the specified files to provide more accurate and context-aware code completions. And there may be practical limits to how much content Copilot can effectively consume from a file at once. I usually select the content of a currently opened file, to make sure it is part of the context.

Comment: yes I do the same, but we are talking about 30k lines long docs+xml :-)

Comment: @jave.web Wouldn't that be way over the [GitHub Copilot's tokens limit](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/56619)?

Comment: I guess so... I would somehow imagine the copilot soft to have some automated inner system that can automatically do the work in the middle - splitit to multiple requests and somhow combine the final answer :/ I guess I'm ahead of time again :-)

Answer (score 1):

Currently (jan 2024) copilot will reference only one file at a time. IF you want it to take your CSS and JS into consideration, you need to either paste it into the conversation, or include it all in one file.

Comment: ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/73848372/11107541

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: you can use @workspace, but it will hardly do what you expect if the files are too big...